# what does modulo set mean?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modules

While I was reading [this article](http://doctrina.org/How-RSA-Works-With-Examples.html) I have faced this term ***Set Of Integers Modulo P*** but I am a little confused so I can't understand why the author defined it as:

$Zp$ = $\{$ $0,1,2,...,p−1$ $\}$

Is called the set of integers modulo $p$ (or mod $p$ for short). It is a set that contains Integers from $0$ up until $p−1$.

what I know about the modulo is that it is the remainder an division operation so what does the modulo set mean?

Comment: Simply google "modular arithmetic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the set of integers mod $p$. Mod $p$ does, like you said, deal with remainders of integers when divided by $p$. But the only possible remainders when dividing by $p$ are $0, 1, ..., p-1$. Thus the set of integers "mod $p$" is the set of these possible remainders.